# React-Native: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: android, react-native

I'm newbie to react-native, followed the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) guide and now I'm just trying to compile my first android app. Unfortunately, the console outputs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/27.1.1/support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar
> Could not find livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/livedata-core/1.1.0/livedata-core-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/viewmodel/1.1.0/viewmodel-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/runtime/1.1.0/runtime-1.1.0.aar
```

What steps did I skip? My platform is Windows 10 and my Android Phone 7.1.1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved just adding:

`maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`

to: android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

I guess it is a gradle version issue

Comment: It fit the question!

Comment: thanks it works. 
but can you say why?