# error: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i have un app using "flutter_youtube_download" , when run application on simulator  debug console show this error below ,flutter youtube download version 0.0.5 null safety , i have tried so many solution like add maven to build.gradle and other but still same error what should i do help me pleassssse :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/master-SNAPSHOT/android-youtubeExtractor-master-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/master-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/HaarigerHarald/android-
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/github/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/master-SNAPSHOT/android-youtubeExtractor-master-SNAPSHOT.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :flutter_youtube_downloader
```

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
         
    }
     
     
   repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956232/react-native-could-not-resolve-all-files-for-configuration-appdebugcompilecl